# homogeneous spaces are real analytic

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $H$ be a closed subgroup. How to prove that the homogeneous space $G/H$ is a real analytic manifold?

Comment: It depends on how much Lie theory you know. Do you already know that $G$ has a natural real-analytic structure and $H$ is a real-analytic subgroup?